# different jdk versions returned when requesting system

Tags: java, linux, version

i wanna understang why these three commands not always return the same jdk.
In the third request, the jdk is not the same.

1- when i launch this command

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep 'java.home'
```

it returns to me

```
java.home usrlibjvmjava-11-openjdk-amd64
```

2- when i launch this

```
cd /etc/alternatives/java
ls -l | grep "java ->"
```

it returns the same jdk

```
java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

3-but in this third case :

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

it returns an another jdk

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
```

someone could explain why ?

Comment: Practically it is always the same jdk. `java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64`should be a symlink to `java-11-openjdk-amd64`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved myself.
I got some symbolic links in my /usr/lib/jvm

```
 java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-11-openjdk-amd64
 java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

so, all is well